# How do I access the emulator control line in Android?

Tags: android, command-line, time, timezone

I'm trying to change the time zone on my Android emulator. I'm using Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine. To do this it says to enter some commands in the command line, but doesn't say how to access the command line!

So how do I access the command line in Windows 7 using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Hit `windows + r` type in `cmd`

then type in

```
adb shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line means the windows command line.  Click the windows orb and search cmd.  It might not work initially because you have to set the PATH variables properly.

Instructions from Android Developers site [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

On Windows, right-click on My Computer, and select Properties. Under the Advanced tab, hit the Environment Variables button, and in the dialog that comes up, double-click on Path (under System Variables). Add the full path to the tools/ directory to the path.